# Google Chrome Extension that can bypass surveys?

Tags: chrome, survey

Today I am looking for an extension on Google Chrome that has one goal in mind:

> To bypass most online annoying surveys and skip to the download

Ideally I would prefer an extension that can simply bypass fileups.net surveys. The reason I am looking for an extension to bypass surveys is because obviously they are annoying and ask for details such as your email so in the future they can just ship of your email address to other companies so you receive non-stop spam which I encountered numerous times before. Any suggestions?

Also some nice to haves are....

- Can bypass Fileice surveys

Is there an extension on Chrome that can do this?

Comment: Could you give a sample site with a fileups.net or Fileice surveys?

Comment: @galacticninja- Heres one > http://fileice.net/download.php?file=3kpgh